# xcode4: Where are the User Scripts?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

xcode used to have a whole bucket of user scripts and an easy way to add shell scripts to the environment.

[Here is an example.](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/helpful-xcode-user-scripts/)

While the User Scripts are still in the xcode 4 help file, I cannot find any way to access the scripts in xcode 4.

Did these disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link can be a sort of help to you. After you log in to Apple's devs forums:  https://devforums.apple.com/message/380673#380673.

One user wrote there:

> "As far as I know it's gone. I hope
>   they bring it back before the final
>   release. Until then your only option
>   is to drop it in ~/Library/Scripts and
>   then go to File > Services > Service
>   Preferences... and set a keyboard
>   shortcut."

I thinks it's the only way to go for now...