# Where the Xcode user scripts at?

Tags: xcode, macos, userscripts

An aside to [xcode4: Where are the User Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658839/xcode4-where-are-the-user-scripts) : if I went ahead and upgraded to Xcode4, are the scripts still present anywhere in the filesystem? I realize I cannot call them from Xcode anymore, but can I still retrieve the raw text content that was once there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4 was misbehaving on me in various other ways, so I put Xcode 3 back (had to run setup twice), and here they are, my cute little scripts, just as I left them.